# commit to same repository from different Xcode project

Tags: xcode, github

I'm working with a teammate on Xcode, and we plan to use GitHub to collaborate on the same Xcode project, so it would be like I make changes on my side, commit to the repo ,and then he can pull from the repository, make changes and commit again.But it seems that it is only possible to commit to a repository from the Xcode project which the Git Repository was created from. IS there any way for me to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Pull the repo on your other xcode project

Comment: uhh it throws me a bunch of other error